# Is there any indication that Ehlnofey might be... us?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls

In the Mythic Era of "The Elder Scrolls" lore, Nirn was populated solely by the ancestors of the beast-races (Argonians, Khajiit, Sload, etc.) It is said that fragments of another world - Ehlnofey - crashed on Nirn, bringing with it the peoples of that planet (who were also referred to as "the Ehlnofey"). Basically, aliens landed on Nirn.

These "aliens" split into two factions, one eventually becoming the bloodlines of Men and the other becoming the bloodlines of Mer. The faction that would evolve into the Mer had part of their city intact, and therefore had access to technology and architecture the peoples of Nirn had never seen before. This is likely the basis of Aldmeri domination over "magic".

**Are there any indications in the games or books that Ehlnofey might have been Earth, or an Earth colony/ship?**

I know this is probably just fishing, but it would explain why Elves and Men are genetically compatible (they can have children together, after all). It would also explain how items from Nirn can land on the earth of Fallout or vice versa - they're in the same galaxy!

Comment: what items do you mean land on the appropriate planet?

Comment: @Thomas - not sure what you're asking. My question is whether or not the "aliens" that arrived on chunks of Ehlnofey (the planet and the people are both called 'Ehlnofey' in Elder Scrolls lore) could be humans from Earth or an Earth-founded colony

Comment: @Omegacron I think Thomas is asking which items show up in both universes

Comment: I always figured that stuff like [Fall of the Space Core](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fall_of_the_Space_Core,_Vol_1) were supposed to be joke DLC and not a serious entry into the lore, just like Maiq the Liar having fourth-wall breaking powers in some games.

Comment: The Hero is a third of the Enantiomorph, the trio that echoes throughout Nirn’s history. And the Hero is always controlled by the player; that’s what makes him or her the Hero. So *The Elder Scrolls* does have some notion of the influence of our world on theirs. Whether or not that extends to the Ehlnofey, I do not know.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Wouldn't they *have* to be us? I mean we are, in fact, "Men."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ehlnofey are not aliens, they are original spirits that have up some of their power to inhabit Nirn. Other original spirits became the Aedra and Deadra, while others known as the Magna Ge flew into the sky to get to Aetherius, creating holes in the sky that became the stars. Some Ehlnofey became the rules of nature, and some became the ancestors of the modern races.

Sources: 
http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Ehlnofey
http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Magna_Ge